# Collecting data from nested maps in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What is the idiomatic way of counting certain properties of a nested map of maps in Clojure?

Given the following datastructure:

```
(def x {
    :0 {:attrs {:attributes {:dontcare "something"
                             :1 {:attrs {:abc "some value"}}}}}
    :1 {:attrs {:attributes {:dontcare "something"
                             :1 {:attrs {:abc "some value"}}}}}
    :9 {:attrs {:attributes {:dontcare "something"
                             :5 {:attrs {:xyz "some value"}}}}}})
```

How can i produce the desired output:

```
(= (count-attributes x) {:abc 2, :xyz 1})
```

This is my best effort so far:

```
(defn count-attributes 
 [input]
 (let [result (for [[_ {{attributes :attributes} :attrs}] x
                 :let [v (into {} (remove (comp not :attrs) (vals attributes)))]]
              (:attrs v))]
      (frequencies result)))
```

Which produces the following:

```
{{:abc "some value"} 2, {:xyz "some value"} 1}
```

Comment: I think that the answer with `tree-seq` is much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like building such functions with threadding so the steps are easier to read

```
user> (->> x 
           vals                    ; first throw out the keys
           (map #(get-in % [:attrs :attributes]))  ; get the nested maps
           (map vals)              ; again throw out the keys
           (map #(filter map? %))  ; throw out the "something" ones. 
           flatten                 ; we no longer need the sequence sequences
           (map vals)              ; and again we don't care about the keys
           flatten                 ; the map put them back into a list of lists
           frequencies)            ; and then count them.
{{:abc "some value"} 2, {:xyz "some value"} 1}
```

`(remove (comp not :attrs)` is a lot like `select-keys`
`for [[_ {{attributes :attributes} :attrs}]` reminds me of `get-in`

Comment: Nathan Marz's "Specter" lib be might useful for this: https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter

Answer (score 1):

I find `tree-seq` very useful for these cases:

```
(frequencies (filter #(and (map? %) (not-any? map? (vals %))) (tree-seq map? vals x)))
```